# One PHP file can't see the change of session variable done by another PHP file

Tags: php, ajax, session

Session variable `login` is used both by `form.php` and `ajaxfunc.php`. The value of the variable is set by `function changeLogin()` from `form.php`. To read the value of this variable both files use `function readLogin()` which is located in the file `shared.inc.php`. File `form.php` starts with `session_start();` and then includes `shared.inc.php`. File `ajaxfunc.php` also includes `shared.inc.php` and designed to be used by AJAX requests from JS functions inside `form.php`. The problem is that whenever the form changes the session variable, `readLogin()` invoked from `ajaxfunc.php` always returns the same old initial value of `login`. How can I get the updated value of the session variable?

Comment: Can you pls share the code instead of sharing the file names or function names.?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. The value of the session variable is passed to `ajaxfunc.php` using `ajaxreq.open("GET", "ajaxfunc.php?login=" + loginVal, true);`